# Weblogic server installation in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, ubuntu-server, ubuntu-16.04

my setup,

am using virtual box vm for installation of weblogic server fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls.jar on top of Ubuntu 16.04 server

installed oracle java using 
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer

now java is installed in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java and i have set java_home = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

have placed the file fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls.jar in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

when trying to install weblogic server from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle using java -jar fmw_12.2.1.1.0_wls.jar it fails with the error message as

preparing to launch the oracle universal installer from /tmp/OralInstall2016 
Exception in thread "main" java.long.UnsatisifiedLinkError: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jrelib/amad64/libawt_xawt.so:libXender.so cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory

Please advise

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a pre-existing provisioning framework like https://forge.puppet.com/biemond/orawls ?

Comment: Hi Trent, 
we are yet to migrate our infrastructure to Puppet or Chef. I create this complete build vm for the developers and put it in the share repository so the developers when need will copy it from the share and use it in their virtual box. Am thinking a long term solution of slowly migrating these task's into Vagrant, docker with chef or puppet automation.

Comment: There's reference implementations for that, too: https://github.com/biemond/biemond-orawls-vagrant

Comment: hi thanks on that. i'll go through it, can you give me suggestions for the error i reported

Comment: Have you checked whether you installed a 32bit vs 64bit jvm?

Comment: i have checked that using java -d64 -version which gave me the results 
ava version "1.8.0_101"
Java (TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_1010-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

I presume it's a 64bit jvm correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: Any updates on my comment or on my issue?

Comment: Tried installing the libXrender library using apt-get? Clearly AWT expects it, but you might not have it installed.

Comment: Hi Trent/all,
Presently am using quick installer with lxde gui component in ubuntu 16.04 server and everything is perfectly fine. I forgot to install GUI in ubuntu server

Comment: OK, I guess libXrender is needed by GUI components and was already installed.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing pre-requisites. Perhaps there are more, but the one you're referred is because of missing X-Windows subsystem. Easiest just to invoke:

```
$ sudo apt install -y xterm
```

I hope it will help,
Jarek